# Magento: Adding a Product: Tier Price

Tags: magento

I was wondering whether anyone could guide me on the purpose
of the Tier Price section when adding a product to the catalog.
What is a tier price and how does this section of the page work
in terms of what can be accomplished with this field?

Magento documentation is a bit limited, not sure where to find
this information, and would like to have a grasp on the genric
concept as well as the details.

Comment: Google Google Google http://extend.thecartpress.com/ecommerce-plugins/tier-price/

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). If you want your name attached to your posts, fill out your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tier prices are remarkably easy - once you understand them.  Getting your head around all fo the things Magento throws at you at first can be overwhelming and make you overthink some things.  So, hopefully I can explain tier prices in Magento a bit for you.

Tiered prices allow you to have multiple prices based on the quantity that the user wants to purchase (and the customer group).  For example:

Qty   |  Price
   1   |   $10
   5   |   $12
   10  |   $13

Customer groups (if you don't know what they are) allow you to group various customers together and set up different rules and settings for each group - like separate price tiers.  For example, my company is a B2B supply-level company, and in order to have an account on our site, you have to be a verified distributor of ours, or member of a sales organization that does business in our industry.  Our customers would get mad if their customers were able to logon to our site and see what they (as our distributors) are paying.    To remedy the situation, we have one price tier we show for the "Not Logged In" customer group that contains MSRP.  We also don't want to have to make the customer work too hard in figuring out what they will actually be paying, so we then have a "Logged In" price tier that displays the actual distributor prices.

We also have a third price tier for some of our "Rewards" program customers that do a certain dollar amount of business with us in a specific time period - but that is just another example of how it can be used.

Hopefully this helps.  Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Cool, I like how you used customer groups to distinguish what they see as logged out - the manufacturer's suggested retail price, as opposed to when they're logged in - the price based on the category assigned to the customer, as well as a third rewards group. You could even have different rewards customers group dependent on the types of customers (level of business done with your company).